# Cannot start game in pygame in into screen

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

In my simple into program I have a start button and checking for events, if start is clicked, I want the start text to change colors and then I want into to be changed to false so that the game starts. This never happens and the pygame is stuck in into screen without stopping. I want the while loop to start and then it will go to another while loop. What do I to check if start is clicked, change the text color, and then end the while loop in the following code?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 60  # frames per second setting
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 800))

window_width = 540
window_height = 800

#Title screen fonts
fontObj2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 60)
start = fontObj2.render("Start", True,(255,255,255))

into=True

while into==True:
    screen.blit(start, (window_width / 2, 600))

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Closes game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif start.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            x, y = event.pos
            if start.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                start = fontObj2.render("Start", True, (192,192,192))
                into=False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            if start.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                start = fontObj2.render("Start", True, (192,192,192))
                into = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to start off you can get rid of  `start.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())` since you already defined it in `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`.

Your code doesn't work as you wanted because the location of `start.get_rect()` isn't where it's located on the screen. If you print it, you will see `<rect(0, 0, 140, 61)>` which is a rect on the top left corner.

To fix this, you simply need to change it to `start.get_rect(x=window_width / 2, y=600) #where you blit the font` to set the location of the rect.

So to refrain:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 60 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 800))

window_width = 540
window_height = 800

fontObj2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 60)
start = fontObj2.render("Start", True,(255,255,255))

into=True

while into: #Equivalent to into == True
    screen.blit(start, (window_width / 2, 600))

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #got rid of another if statement
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            if start.get_rect(x=window_width / 2, y=600).collidepoint(x, y): #changed start.get_rect
                start = fontObj2.render("Start", True, (192,192,192))
                into = False

    #same as before
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```